# How to return a value based on whether two columns contains values present in other columns

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have four columns to compare against and a fifth one which contains the target value. I need to compare the four columns (2 each) and if they match then return the corresponding value in the fifth column. One of the columns requires comparing using the typical = sign while the other column requires checking if the other column contains part of the text. I tried using `regexmatch` but I couldn't get the formula to return the values as I'd wanted.

Here is the link to the google sheets file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13RotkFBSOTylN6YOxPjzYDNWwYtCXo6Ewh6UtCi0i1E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A15, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(D2:D15, 1, 0))))&"♦"&B2:B15, 
 {D2:D15&"♦"&E2:E15, F2:F15}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((D2:D15=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A15, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(D2:D15, 1, 0)))))*(B2:B15=E2:E15), F2:F15, ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: There is a small challenge @player0, D,E AND F are keys meaning A and B gets data from the 3 columns, not vice versa. They don't have to match strictly as in row 2 and 5 which have values. As long as the key exists D,E,F, we should use the data to return the value using the first 2 columns A and B. I have explained in the google sheets, please have a look. I was probably not very clear with my explanation.